# MKOverlayPathView Trouble enabling user to define pathWidth

Tags: objective-c, mapkit, mkoverlay

Ok so I'm using Apples IOS Breadcrumb [Sample Code][1] .

I've a slider to the BreadcrumbViewController.xib called   "lineWidth" and have a UIlabel which shows the value of the slider being changed called "sliderLabel". This I can do with relative ease.

Although now I want whatever number is in the sliderLabel to affect the CrumbPath lineWidth which at the moment is in CrumbPathView.m

```
{
CrumbPath *crumbs = (CrumbPath *)(self.overlay);

CGFloat lineWidth = MKRoadWidthAtZoomScale(zoomScale);
```

Now this can be changed to

```
CGFloat lineWidth = 200;
```

Or  whatever. 
so my question is how do I store the value of the sliderLabel located in the BreadcrumbViewController.xib (which is linked to the BreadcrumbViewController.h &.m) and retrieve the stored value (INT) in the CrumbPathView.m?

Im still learning so be nice.

Thank you in advance.